# How to change the signing developer identity for iOS app in Android studio? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, apple-developer-account

I am working with flutter and recently I bought an apple developer account to enable some extra features in my app. My problem is that when I am running the app in my iOS device through the android studio, it keeps the old signing identity (free account) and it does not use the paid account. So when I built the app I got this message

*Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "Apple Development: my_email_from_free_account (certificate number)"*

However, when I am running the app thought Xcode the configuration is the correct one, the app uses the paid signing account and it runs normally.

How can I set the same configuration also in android studio?

> Failed to build iOS app
> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
> ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
> Building a deployable iOS app requires a selected Development Team with a
> Provisioning Profile. Please ensure that a Development Team is selected by:
> 1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
> open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
> 2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
> in the project settings
> 3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected under Signing & Capabilities > Team.
> You may need to:
> - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
> - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
> - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
> - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
> 4- Build or run your project again

For more information, please visit:
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#deploy-to-ios-devices

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing

Comment: yes, so the problem was that I had created 2 runners in Xcode. By default I think Xcode runs the first runner with name "Runner". So, the second one I had created didn't run. Therefore, try to check if you have multiple runners to manage to run the one you need